# Android app does not refer to new URL

Tags: android, eclipse

I have changed the url for my web api in android app. I have uninstalled the app from device as well, still when I run the project from eclipse it fails with message "connection refused to 192.168.x.x ". I have changed the url to new ip address but it doesn't resolve that.

Any lights ?

Comment: No idea, how about some more info on the problem? Post the code where you set your URL, and where you use that URL to connect. Chances are you'll find the problem yourself doing that :)

Comment: Problem solved. Restarted the eclipse and now it takes the new url.